# Horizontal mirror/flip webcam image for video conference on MacOS

Tags: mac, webcam

I am looking for a solution to **horizontally (or vertically) mirror/flip the webcam image (not rotate) on MacOS** on the hardware or driver level.  The ultimate goal is to use a mirrored video stream in Webex, Zoom, or Skype.

I have seen solutions involving virtual cameras (e.g., OBS, Logitech Capture), which work, but this requires additional software and processes to run in parallel.

I am **looking for a solution that works on the OS, driver, or hardware level to flip the image**.  The solution could be a specific webcam  having a driver that allows flipping the webcam or an option on MacOs that I have not found.

Unfortunately, the Logitech cameras I have and their companion software (Camera Settings) only allow for adjustments of brightness, zoom, etc. but not for flipping the image.

**Update to provide additional clarification on the use case: The background is that my webcam points first at a mirror -- hence, I need to flip the video screen to "undo the mirroring".**

Under Windows, the device driver ("device properties") for many Logitech webcams offers the "orientation" option, allowing to flip the image horizontally or vertically.  I am looking for a similar option under MacOS -- or for another webcam offering this option.

Any suggestions, ideas, or experiences are very welcome!

Comment: Skype mirrors anyway - I see no option to not mirror. [I don't use the others]

Answer (score 1):

Zoom has an option in the app Preferences to mirror the video image at your end.

[image]

If you're looking to *send* a mirrored image, then that's probably extremely non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your response -- unfortunately, this mirrors/flips the video stream only locally, but the remote participants still see the original picture.